# (SQL) Creating a sequential last transaction table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with client´s transactions and i want to create a table:

```
Day          Last Transaction  Client
2020-01-01   2020-01-01        Alex   <- Client first transaction
2020-01-02   2020-01-01        Alex
2020-01-03   2020-01-03        Alex   <- New transaction
.....
```

Every day I want to know the last transaction of each client.

I have table with every transaction of each client with *id* and *creation_date*. And i created a table with days of year and was expecting to use pandas to process the result to get what i wanted, but i realised it is really costly

I tried this but got stuck:

```
      "created_at",
      id,
      date_  
   from
       (select -- Create a table with every transaction of each client
       distinct
          "on_behalf_of",
          cast("created_at" as date) created_at
        from raw_data."raw_transactions")
   right join
   (select   -- Create a table with days, client id and first transaction
      date_add('day',s.n, first_date_year) date_,
      id,
      First_transaction
      from ( -- Sequence of days starting at 2020-01-01
          select date_trunc('year', date '2020-01-01') as first_date_year) as genarate_seq
      cross join
          unnest(sequence(0,date_diff('day',date'2020-01-01',now()))) s (n)
      cross join
          (select   -- Client id and first transaction
                on_behalf_of id_pay,
                cast(min(created_at) as date) First_transaction
            from raw_data.raw_transactions
            group by 1)
    where date_add('day',s.n, first_date_year) >= First_transaction)
  on "on_behalf_of" = id and created_at = date_
  order by 2 asc , 3 asc ; 

I am using athena that use presto sql.
```

Answer (score 1):

> Every day i want to know the last transaction of each client.

I am unsunre how your convoluted query really relates to your question. Assuming that column `id` represents the *client* and that `creation_date` is the timestamp of each transaction, you could do this with `distinct on` as follows:

```
select distinct on (id, creation_date::date) 
    id, 
    creation_date::date transaction_day, 
    creation_date transaction_date
from raw_transactions
order by id, creation_date::date, creation_date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Likewise I cannot make much since out of that query. But from the description sounds and looks like you want to capture a running daily history containing the first (assumed from comments in query) and the last transaction (assumed from description and posted results?() for each client into a new table.  Guess that's the idea behind the calendar table. However, that is insufficient and no definition I'll just build my own.  
The approach is to capture the min and max transaction date by client where the dates are prior to or equal to a specified date (run_date). That allows rerunning for a day if necessary or if it does not run on some date. The result then inserted into the history table.

```
-- create the history table
create table client_tran_date_hist(  
       run_date date
     , client_id integer
     , first_tran_date date
     , last_tran_date date);
alter table client_tran_date_hist add constraint client_tran_date_hist_pk primary key (client_id, run_date);
```

Populate the history table for a specified date (note: routine does NOT roll forward should a rerun for a prior date.)

```
-- Procedure to populate history table for specified date (note: function returns void = procedure -- well almost) 

create or replace function client_tran_date_history(run_date_in date default current_date)
   returns void 
   language sql strict
as $$  
   insert into client_tran_date_hist( run_date, client_id, first_tran_date, last_tran_date) 
         select run_date_in 
              , cid                              -- client id
              , min_dt                           -- first tran date
              , max_dt                           -- last tran dats
         from ( -- get first and last tran date for each client
                select run_date_in              
                     , client_id             cid
                     , min(created_at)::date min_dt
                     , max(created_at)::date max_dt
                  from raw_transactions
                 where created_at::date <= run_date_in
                 group by client_id
              ) r
         where not exists ( -- except existing clients without dates a changed
                            select null  
                              from client_tran_date_hist 
                             where run_date        = run_date_in
                               and client_id       = cid
                               and first_tran_date = min_dt
                               and last_tran_date  = max_dt
                          )
   on conflict on constraint client_tran_date_hist_pk  -- when clients already exists 
      do update                                        -- updated both dates
         set first_tran_date = excluded.first_tran_date
           , last_tran_date  = excluded.last_tran_date;
$$;
```

Routine to generate a transaction history report.

```
-- function to generate report
create or replace function client_tran_date_history_report (start_date_in date default current_date
                                                           ,end_date_in   date default current_date
                                                           ) 
  returns table ( run_date              date
                , last_transaction_date date
                , client                text
                )
  language sql strict
as $$
    select h.run_date       
         , h.last_tran_date
         , c.name
      from client_tran_date_hist h
      join clients               c
        on (c.id = h.client_id)
     where run_date between start_date_in and end_date_in; 
$$;
```

Test procedure. The actual dates and clients table in the report function will need to be supplied from your system.

```
do $$
begin
     perform client_tran_date_history(run_date_in => date '2020-01-06');
     perform client_tran_date_history(run_date_in => date '2020-01-13');
     perform client_tran_date_history(run_date_in => date '2020-01-20'); 
     perform client_tran_date_history(run_date_in => date '2020-02-20');
end ; 
$$; 

select * from client_tran_date_history_report (start_date_in => '2020-01-01')
where client = 'Alex'
order by client, run_date;
```

I hope this gives you the appropriate direction to proceed.